# Diacritic Replacement in VBScript using the "Unicode Collation Algorithm"

Tags: unicode, vbscript

I am writing a function to normalize diacritic (and other non-a-zA-Z0-9 chars) in a string.

In [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url?rq=1#comment221356_7696) in a related post, [tchrist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/153355/tchrist) suggests not hard-coding any mappings e.g. `"p̈"="p"`, and instead, to use the Unicode Collation Algorithm.

How can one implement this in vbscript?

Comment: As with every implementation, you open your preferred editor and start debugging. You [may not want to bother](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/), though.